# How do I get rid of extra data in the NodeJs ByteBuffer?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having trouble understanding why the ByteBuffer does not keep track of its length.  I simply want to append to the bytebuffer and get back what I put into it.  Instead, I ether get random junk at the end, or if I compact the buffer it truncates my input.

Here is an example of both:

```
nodejs -e 'ByteBuffer=require("bytebuffer"); b=new ByteBuffer(); b.append("word"); b=b.clone(); b.printDebug()'
ByteBufferNB(offset=4,markedOffset=-1,limit=16,capacity=16)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
 77 6F 72 64<6B 14 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>  wordk...........


nodejs -e 'ByteBuffer=require("bytebuffer"); b=new ByteBuffer(); b.append("word"); b.compact(); b.printDebug()'
ByteBufferNB(offset=0,markedOffset=-1,limit=12,capacity=12)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
<6B 14 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>              k...........
```

Does someone know how to wrap this up creating buffer that contains exactally what was put into it?  It shouldn't be necessary to manually set the length.

Comment: I found a work-around: `b = b.copy(0, b.offset)`

Comment: https://github.com/dcodeIO/ByteBuffer.js